# MinGW does not see the library in NetBeans

Tags: c, netbeans, mingw, allegro, allegro5

I am trying to configure compilation of a project in NetBeans.

[image]

I downloaded the latest version of the library assembly from [GitHub](https://github.com/liballeg/allegro5/releases/download/5.2.6.0/allegro-x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-9.2.0-posix-seh-static-5.2.6.0.zip). Unpacked to the root of the system directory.

[image]

In NetBeans indicated the path to store the "include, bin, lib" directory.

[image]

When writing code, the IDE pulls up the necessary headers and the code looks correct, without errors. When compiling, in the project properties specified the necessary keys: **-lallegro_dialog -lallegro_primitives -lallegro**

[image]

But for some reason, when compiling libraries are not pulled and Netbeans throws errors.

[image]

```
cd 'C:\NetBeans\AllegroTest'
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/NetBeans/AllegroTest'
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/allegrotest.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/NetBeans/AllegroTest'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
gcc -lallegro_dialog -lallegro_primitives -lallegro    -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/allegrotest build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lallegro_dialog
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lallegro_primitives
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lallegro
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/allegrotest.exe] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/NetBeans/AllegroTest'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/NetBeans/AllegroTest'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

СОБРАТЬ FAILED (значение выхода 2,, общее время: 453ms)
```

If i don't use keys **-lallegro_dialog -lallegro_primitives -lallegro** then

```
cd 'C:\NetBeans\AllegroTest'
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/NetBeans/AllegroTest'
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/allegrotest.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/NetBeans/AllegroTest'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
gcc     -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/allegrotest build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o 
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
C:\NetBeans\AllegroTest/main.c:23: undefined reference to `al_install_system'
C:\NetBeans\AllegroTest/main.c:25: undefined reference to `al_show_native_message_box'
C:\NetBeans\AllegroTest/main.c:30: undefined reference to `al_create_display'
C:\NetBeans\AllegroTest/main.c:34: undefined reference to `al_show_native_message_box'
C:\NetBeans\AllegroTest/main.c:39: undefined reference to `al_init_primitives_addon'
C:\NetBeans\AllegroTest/main.c:40: undefined reference to `al_install_keyboard'
C:\NetBeans\AllegroTest/main.c:42: undefined reference to `al_create_event_queue'
C:\NetBeans\AllegroTest/main.c:46: undefined reference to `al_show_native_message_box'
C:\NetBeans\AllegroTest/main.c:51: undefined reference to `al_get_keyboard_event_source'
C:\NetBeans\AllegroTest/main.c:51: undefined reference to `al_register_event_source'
C:\NetBeans\AllegroTest/main.c:52: undefined reference to `al_get_display_event_source'
C:\NetBeans\AllegroTest/main.c:52: undefined reference to `al_register_event_source'
C:\NetBeans\AllegroTest/main.c:57: undefined reference to `al_wait_for_event'
C:\NetBeans\AllegroTest/main.c:109: undefined reference to `al_map_rgb'
C:\NetBeans\AllegroTest/main.c:109: undefined reference to `al_draw_filled_rectangle'
C:\NetBeans\AllegroTest/main.c:110: undefined reference to `al_flip_display'
C:\NetBeans\AllegroTest/main.c:111: undefined reference to `al_map_rgb'
C:\NetBeans\AllegroTest/main.c:111: undefined reference to `al_clear_to_color'
C:\NetBeans\AllegroTest/main.c:114: undefined reference to `al_destroy_display'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/allegrotest.exe] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/NetBeans/AllegroTest'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/NetBeans/AllegroTest'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

СОБРАТЬ FAILED (значение выхода 2,, общее время: 1s)
```

[Then I recorded a visual video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zr9NmUfM4Sw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was dealing with was I solved. The fact is that I am from Russia, and I have Russian localization in the operating system and there are Russian letters on the way. Because of this, it was not possible to access the attached library. But I fixed everything, now everything compiles successfully for me.

I managed to compile using [THIS](https://github.com/liballeg/allegro_winpkg/releases) library package. Initially, I thought of downloading each library individually, but then again I carefully looked at everything on the main site. I managed to successfully compile using these keys:

```
-lallegro_monolith-static -static -ljpeg -ldumb -lwebp \
-lFLAC -lvorbisfile -lvorbis -logg -lphysfs -lfreetype \
-lpng16 -ldsound -lgdiplus -luuid -lkernel32 -lwinmm \
-lpsapi -lopengl32 -lglu32 -luser32 -lcomdlg32 -lgdi32 \
-lshell32 -lole32 -ladvapi32 -lws2_32 -lshlwapi -lpthread \
-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -lz -lopusfile -lopus
```

or

```
-lallegro_dialog-static -lallegro_acodec-static -lallegro_audio-static \
-lallegro_image-static -lallegro_primitives-static -lallegro_ttf-static \
-lallegro_font-static -lallegro-static -static -ljpeg -ldumb -lwebp -lFLAC \
-lvorbisfile -lvorbis -logg -lphysfs -lfreetype -lpng16 -ldsound -lgdiplus \
-luuid -lkernel32 -lwinmm -lpsapi -lopengl32 -lglu32 -luser32 -lcomdlg32 \
-lgdi32 -lshell32 -lole32 -ladvapi32 -lws2_32 -lshlwapi -lpthread \
-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -lz -lopusfile -lopus
```

Answer (score 0):

Your toolchain is 32-bit, but the library you set up in NetBeans is built for 64 bits.